# How to separate compressed words from each other in 05AB1E?

Tags: compression, esoteric-languages, 05ab1e

05AB1E is a golfing language and it has a large dictionary of words which can be implemented to the code using a single-character command or multi-character command.

Is there any way to separate the compressed words in case a string contains multiple implementation commands?

This is my 05AB1E code: `”ŽØ¢©„‚…”`

Explanation:

```
”     # begin string, separate words with space, title-case

ŽØ    # compressed word "happy"

¢©    # compressed word "birthday"

„     # compressed word "to"

‚…    #compressed word "you"

”     # end string
```

I am trying to print "Happy Birthday To You", but instead it prints `Happy Birthday County…`, because the compiler confuses `„‚` to a compressed word `county`, leaving `…` alone. It should read first `„`, then `‚…`, and this is where separation would be useful.

You can find all 05AB1E commands in [here.](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/info.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To index into the word list, you always need two parts, a "high" one for the hundreds, and a "low" one for the ones (just like you did with `Ž` for 12 and `Ø` for 79 to get "happy" at index 1279, and with `¢` for 26 and `©` for 33 to get "birthday" at index 2633).

Therefore, to get the word "to" at index 3 (which you would read as 003), just prepend your `„` for 3 with `€` for 0.

Note that for the word "you" at index 14, you likewise need `€` for 0 and `î` for 14, not `‚` for 1 and `…` for 4 which would instead get you "people" at index 104.

Also note that the trailing marker for string literals (`”` in this case) is optional if there's no other command to access the string, so you might want to just drop it.

```
”ŽØ¢©€„€î
```

```
Happy Birthday To You
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcPco3sPzzi06NDKR01rHjXMA5KH1/3/DwA)